# How to get my button to go underneath my form when reaching mobile width using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I have a large button on the left (dashed border) and a form on the right. When you change your screen/viewports width to 550px or less the button goes above the form and changes its height/width.

I would like for the button to go underneath the form (prependTo) at 550px or less. **Using JS**

I have a **[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8obnwksb/)** set up with my prepend javascript code but its not working and im not quite sure what I did wrong.

Have a look?

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w > 550 && $('.addnewflavorimg').children().length > 1) {
            $('.addnewflavorimg').prependTo( $('.formy') );
        } else if (w < 550 && $('.formy').children().length > 1) {
            $('.addnewflavorimg').prependTo( $('.formy') );
        }
    });
});
```

**[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8obnwksb/)**

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

First - Include jQuery in your fiddle via external resources.

I tried to make minimum changes as possible to the existing fiddle to get it to work (so that you can figure it out), so it is definitely not the ideal way to do it.
Especially because you are using `children().length` which can change if your HTML changes. SO you might want to think of a better way to do it. Follow the notes at the end.

Replace the JS part in the following way and it will work.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w > 550 && $('.addnewflavorimg').children().length > 1) {
            $('.addnewflavorimg').prependTo( $('.formy') );
        } else if (w < 550) {
            $('.addnewflavorimg').appendTo( $('.formy') );
        }
    });
});
```

P.S.

- Make sure you call the same function in the resize handler in the
  beginning (if the width is already below 550, window resize might not
  fire)
- You might want to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for cross-platform peace.